# Contact Form 7 send to multiple contacts at once upon user selection

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Hi there I am creating a contact form in Wordpress contact form 7 and I'd like to send emails to multiple recipients at once if user selects "all"

I had a look at this but doesn't seem to document if you can send to multiple recipients at once
http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/ 
e.g This is either/or

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
"Sales|sales@example.com"
"Support|support@example.com"]
```

I would like something like

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
"Sales|sales@example.com"
"Support|support@example.com" 
"All|{"ceo@example.com" "sales@example.com" "Support|support@example.com"}]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right path. Try this instead though...

```
"All|ceo@example.com,sales@example.com,support@example.com"
```

I'd also use select* instead of select so the field is required.

So the whole thing would be:

```
[select* your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
"Sales|sales@example.com"
"Support|support@example.com" 
"All|ceo@example.com,sales@example.com,support@example.com"]
```

Let me know if that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: One more question related to this. In the Message Body for recieving the emails I would like to output the text before the pipe, would you know how this is done? E.g CEO, Sales, Support ... Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted so people know there's a solution here. Thanks!

Comment: According to this, [your-recipient] in the message body should do the trick. http://contactform7.com/tag-syntax/#mail_tag

Not sure how it will do formatting multiple recipients though.

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer [_raw_your-recipient]