# Contact form 7 - Multiple receptions

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I just want to show a "subject" dropdown in my contact form and there are two options. Receptions email change by the subject users are selecting. 
Eg: Let's say my options are "General", "HR", "Accounting" If someone selects "Genral" the email shoud go to general@example.com, If someone select "HR" the email should go to hr@example.com like that.

I did this successfully this way.

```
[select* menu-subject "General|general@example.com"]
```

But there is a problem.

I need to show in my message body What's the subject they are selecting.

When I place [menu-subject] in my message body, it will print email address, not the subject.

Like this way.

```
Message body

Subject: general@example.com
```

How can I show subject text instead of email?

Comment: Is it not better to make three forms where the selected subject shows the correspondig form? This way the forms can have different data based on the chosen subject? And the emails will be correct either way. And then if you want to also send the chosen subject with the form you can use `wpcf7_add_shortcode(menu-subject,'custom_function')` `function custom_function{
//Code
}
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contact Form 7 send to multiple contacts at once upon user selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39969194/contact-form-7-send-to-multiple-contacts-at-once-upon-user-selection)

Comment: To get value before pipe, you can use `[_raw_{field name}]` https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Answer (score 0):

[_raw_your-recipient] this is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).